# Why can't I use 'as' when checking if a variable is an enum value?

Tags: c#, object, types, casting, type-conversion

I have an enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    EnumValue1,
    EnumValue2,
}
```

Supposing I have an object that I'd like to check for being a MyEnum object, I get a compile-time error with the first line of:

```
var myEnumValue = enumObject as MyEnum;

if(myEnumValue != null)
{
 ...
}
```

But I could do the following:

```
var myEnumValue = (MyEnum)enumObject;
```

(But that might raise an exception)

So I have to use:

```
if(enumObject is MyEnum)
{
 //and then assign enumObject to a MyEnum object
}
```

instead.

**Question**

Why is the use of `as` not permitted here but casting or using `is` is?

Comment: `as` means: cast if possible, return `null` otherwise. `null` is not a valid value for an enum. You could use `MyEnum?` though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `as` with any value types (except for [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

The reason is that the `as` keyword returns `null` if the object cannot be cast, however, a value type cannot be `null`.

Comment: "You cannot use as with any value types." - actually, you can use `as` with **exactly half** the available value types. Think about it... (let me know if you want a hint)

Comment: @MarcGravell yup, I figured out what you mean a few seconds after posting that comment.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerations are value types, which cannot be null. `as` needs a Nullable type to return.

However, if you want to cast a value type safely, you can explicitly use a nullable and define a default value if `as` returns null:

```
var myEnumValue = enumObject as MyEnum? ?? MyEnum.EnumValue1;
```